# Frequent BSODs cause Ethernet connectivity problems

Tags: windows-8, vpn, ethernet, bsod, crash

I have an ongoing issue with frequent and random BSODs, but I’m waiting until I can try to analyze the minidumps to either identify the fault or ask for assistance on that issue. In the meantime, I have this other recurring problem compounding the frustration:

Almost every time a BSOD occurs, upon reboot my Ethernet is dead and refuses to connect. My system tray icon reads “Unidentified network / No Internet access”, and running the useless troubleshooter only tells me that “Ethernet does not have a valid IP configuration”.

Now, I have a VPN app (Private Internet Access) that’s always on and connected at the time of each crash, with the killswitch and DNS leak protection features enabled. I believe this may be related, but not necessarily, as previously when my computer crashed for whatever reason with the VPN active, my connection didn’t suffer afterwards – I just reset it, easy-peasy. This inability to connect after each BSOD is new, which is why I don’t think it’s *necessarily* related to my VPN, but of course I can’t say for sure either way.

I’m no expert, so every time this happens I just throw everything I can think of at it – uninstall the VPN (TAP-Windows) driver, uninstall & reinstall the Ethernet driver, reboot my modem/router, some Command Prompt commands I find online that others said helped fix their connectivity problems (such as `netsh winsock reset`, `netsh int ip reset`, etc. – no idea what they do, but they seem to help sometimes), and a bunch of reboots in between. I’ll also try a system restore at times, though it also never works. All this can take upwards of an hour each time.

Eventually, *something* clicks and my Ethernet connection is reestablished, but by then I’ve usually tried over a dozen things and I have no idea what step, or which combination of steps, did the trick. So the next time a BSOD happens, I’m back at square one.

I understand PIA may be the culprit regarding the connectivity issue and I’ve already sent an email to tech support. But in the meantime, I’d like to ask: What are the ways (such as power-user CMD commands) through which one can completely reset their connection in order to wipe out any glitches or misconfigurations caused by crashes? Is there a guide somewhere to walk you through troubleshooting what exactly is wrong with your adapter? Is uninstalling and reinstalling the LAN driver the end-all be-all?

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Comment: [analyze the crash dumps with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Comment: have you analyzed the dumps?

Comment: I don’t have enough dumps yet – only some crashes produce dumps, and the only one I have doesn’t seem related to the others I’ve had. I want to wait to accumulate a couple more dumps before analyzing them and finding a common cause.

Comment: have you seen more crashes?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I’ve had at least one more crash, but it didn’t leave a minidump, so I have nothing to analyze, unfortunately. It seems 50/50 whether a dump is created after a BSOD right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I still haven’t fixed the BSODs (or positively IDed the cause), but I’ve figured out what causes the Internet connectivity problem and how to resolve it. The VPN’s “Killswitch” feature, which disables your connection whenever the VPN app is running and disconnected, works by removing the network adapter’s IPv4 default gateway; it replaces it when you exit the app normally, but obviously not when the system suddenly crashes. To fix, all I have to do – as I found after endless trial & error – is restart my modem and wait a bit. Almost anticlimactic.

Answer (score 1):

#### Upon reboot my Ethernet is dead and refuses to connect

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thanks for the list. I’ll note the commands down and try them the next time my system BSODs, which shouldn’t be more than a few days from now. I’ll update here with whether or not these commands worked without additional steps. Thanks again.